# zenddebugger not working with mac osx mavericks for php Aptana

Tags: php, macos, osx-mavericks

I installed mac osx mavericks. Now I find that it replaced php 5.3 with 5.4 (and removed php.ini plus some other files), and I cannot debug php scripts - I think because ZendDebugger.so is only available up to php 5.3.

In Aptana, I get:
'Error launching PHP Script
The debug session could not be started.
Please make sure that the debugger is properly configured as a php.ini directive'

php.ini does show:
...
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so"
    zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
    zend_debugger.connector_port=10000
    zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32,192.168.*.*,10.*.*.*
...

And as ZendDebugger.so had been removed by the mavericks installation, I downloaded it(64-bit) from http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/downloads and tried placing ZendDebugger.so in /usr/lib/php/extensions/

If I do a 'php -v' I get:
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so:       dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so, 9): Symbol not found: _output_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/ZendDebugger.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

Because ZendDebugger.so does reside there, I think it must be because it is built for php 5.3 This must also be why Aptana is complaining.

So now, without ZendDebugger.so for php 5.4, I am stuck - or so it seems.

Any insights? Have I missed something? Should I try to go back to php 5.3? Is there a Saas php debugger I can switch to?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Colin G

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=47568) seems to indicate that zend debugger does not support php5.4 yet. However I'm currently using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) with PHP 5.5 and it's working fine. It has all the features of zend debugger, including remote debugging and var dump formatting.

The maintainer has [produced a tool](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) which looks at your phpinfo output and produces personalised installation instructions.

Here is a recent tutorial on [hooking up Aptana to xdebug.](http://php.tutorialhorizon.com/how-to-debug-php-in-aptana-studio/)

Comment: This is useful information, and something I would try if I had not already found a copy of ZendDebugger.so for php5.4. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Hi Colin, I'm experiencing a similar issue. Where did you get a copy of ZendDebugger for php5.4?